# Unable to parse json with List elements inside it

Tags: java, json, spring, rest

I have a Java class which has 2 List Object inside it and i am Json serializing the parent class.

```
@JsonSerialize
public class RequestSalesJson {
    @JsonProperty("nonUniqueSalesList")
    private List<SalesDataJson> getNonUniqueSalesDataJson;
    @JsonProperty("uniqueSalesList")
    private List<SalesDataJson> uniqueSalesDataJson;

    public List<SalesDataJson> getGetNonUniqueSalesDataJson() {
        return getNonUniqueSalesDataJson;
    }

    public void setGetNonUniqueSalesDataJson(List<SalesDataJson> getNonUniqueSalesDataJson) {
        this.getNonUniqueSalesDataJson = getNonUniqueSalesDataJson;
    }

    public List<SalesDataJson> getUniqueSalesDataJson() {
        return uniqueSalesDataJson;
    }

    public void setUniqueSalesDataJson(List<SalesDataJson> uniqueSalesDataJson) {
        this.uniqueSalesDataJson = uniqueSalesDataJson;
    }
}
```

**SalesReturnJson.java**

```
@JsonSerialize
public class SalesReturnJson {
    @JsonProperty("starttime")
    private String startTime;
    @JsonProperty("pn")
    private String partNumber;
    @JsonProperty("so")
    private String SalesOrderNumber;
    @JsonProperty("wo")
    private String workOrderNumber;
    @JsonProperty("loc")
  //other variables declared..
}
```

**Controller.java :-**

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/addAllSalesData",method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public void addAllSalesData(@RequestBody RequestSalesJson requestSalesJsons){
        log.info("POST : '/addSalesData'");
        try{
            System.out.print("In Controller "+requestSalesJsons.getUniqueSalesDataJson());
            //salesService.processSalesData(requestSalesJsons);
        }
        catch(Exception e){
          // return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST).body(e.getMessage());
        }
    }
```

The value here is coming to be null.

Below is the json i am using :-

```
{ "uniqueSalesJson": [{"SO":4000955,"Part Number":"000","Locator":255638,"Lot Number":"P01-2059139","Reservation Quantity":2,"Status":"Released to warehouse","COE":"Fabrication","ORG":"P07","Start_Time":"2017-09-19 11:21:36"},{"SO":4000955,"Part Number":"000","Locator":255652,"Lot Number":"P01-2059140","Reservation Quantity":10,"Status":"Released to warehouse","COE":"Fabrication","ORG":"P07","Start_Time":"2017-09-19 11:21:36"}],"nonUniqueSalesJson":[{"SO":4000992,"Part Number":"1276M84G15","Locator":12345,"Lot Number":"P01-2344141","Reservation Quantity":6,"Status":"PACKED","COE":"Fabrication","ORG":"P07","Start_Time":"2017-09-19 11:21:36"},{"SO":4000992,"Part Number":"1276M84G15","Locator":12345,"Lot Number":"P01-2344141","Reservation Quantity":6,"Status":"PICKED","COE":"Fabrication","ORG":"P07","Start_Time":"2017-09-19 11:21:36"}]}
```

Comment: Add @RestController on top of the RequestMapping

Answer (score 1):

There are some issues in your code that let me doubt that your application compiles. First of all, rename the `SalesReturnJson` class to `SalesDataJson`.
Then check your `@JsonProperty` annotations. The value here must match exactly the property key in the Json String. Refactoring all this stuff will lead you to your root entity class:

```
@JsonSerialize
public class RequestSalesJson {
    @JsonProperty("nonUniqueSalesJson")
    private List<SalesDataJson> nonUniqueSalesDataJson;
    @JsonProperty("uniqueSalesJson")
    private List<SalesDataJson> uniqueSalesDataJson;
    ...
}
```

and your `SalesDataJson` class (missing a lot of attributes which the mapper ignores by configuration):

```
@JsonSerialize
public class SalesDataJson {
    @JsonProperty("Start_Time")
    private String startTime;
    @JsonProperty("Part Number")
    private String partNumber;
    @JsonProperty("SO")
    private String SalesOrderNumber;
}
```

This sample works as expected with the `com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper`

Hope that helps!